# Find parent directory name of a file - Jenkins pipeline

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline

I have some groovy code (Jenkins Pipeline) to loop over a coverage directory and find any files matching a certain pattern. For any files found, I want to determine what their parent directory is named as. These files are currently in sub dirs under a coverage directory.

```
def coverageReportFiles = findFiles(glob: 'coverage/**/coverage-summary.json')
for(file in coverageReportFiles ){
    echo "${file.directory}" // currently prints out 'false'
}
```

Are there any utilities with Jenkins Pipeline steps or anything native in groovy I can use to determine this?

Answer (score 1):

It should be possible with `file.parentFile.name`

Comment: groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: parentFile for class: org.jenkinsci.plugins.pipeline.utility.steps.fs.FileWrapper

Comment: What does `file.path` echo?

Comment: findFiles returns a org.jenkinsci.plugins.pipeline.utility.steps.fs.FileWrapper and not a real file

Answer (score 0):

I tried to get the relative parent folder with below script:

```
def files = findFiles( glob: "**/*.json" ) 
fileParentFolder = "/${files[0].path}" - "/${files[0].name}"
```

Using file path substract file name with separator "/".
This solution works for me, but need care about the path separator "/"